# Wordpress: why is there a copy of wp-includes in my wp-includes?

Tags: wordpress

So I noticed that in the wp-includes folder of one of my sites there are sub-folders named wp-includes and wp-content that i suspect should not be there. These contain the same sub-folders as the ordinary wp-includes and wp-content. I am thinking one of two things may have happened:

1. I have accidentally copied those folders there without noticing.
2. Some wordpress feature or plugin has put copies there for some reason. Here's my question: do you know of any plugin that would do that? A backup plugin like updraft or duplicator perhaps, or maybe Wordpress itself when I upgraded to a newer version? Am I safe to remove those directories?

I discovered it when attempting to use Duplicator and it failed (probably because my hosting service timed out because of too much data) and gave suggestions of files/directories to filter out from te backup process.

Comment: My guess is accidental uploading to the wrong location.   None of my WordPress sites have that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation to you when trying to clean up your server and test various files is to temporarily rename them. Find the directories that you think you no longer need. Change their name. WARNING: This will cause errors on your site if those directories are needed.

Test your website right after you change the directory name. Does it look like everything is working properly? Check your error logs. See anything popping up? If everything looks to work smoothly you can delete the directory now or soon. Make sure to back everything up by downloading the directory!

If there are errors on your website or in your error logs you can rename the directory back to its original name and the errors will go away. This is a method that can be used to test out files on your server that you are unsure of without having to delete directories entirely when unsure if they are needed.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a wise course of action. I renamed the folders and everything seems to work. I have a backup from yesterday so I'll go ahead and delete the folders.  Again, thanks!